# CfEngine Error in policy, clients not taking local policy

Tags: cfengine

I pushed an incorrect syntax policy from policy server into clients, resulting which all clients had an syntax error. Now I have corrected the policy in policy server, the clients are not picking up updated policy,as if cf-agent is not executing failsafe.cf.So is there any way to make clients take up this policy or any reason as to why the cfengine failed this way. Moreover, I didn't change any of update.cf or  failsafe.cf and using ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try running `cf-agent -KI -f update.cf` on one of the failing clients, and see what it tells you? If that doesn't shed any light, try adding `-v` to see the verbose output.

Without knowing more, here are some things that I think could be causing this behavior:

1. `cf-execd` is not running on the clients, so `cf-agent` is not being run.
2. The server is unreachable from the clients for some reason.

Comment: cf-agent -Ki -f update.cf fetched corrected policy from policy servers but it was not being automatically as expected. cf-execd indeed was not running on hosts which i didn't understand as to why it happened. I just wrote a script to log in to every host and bootstrap the cfengine again and now everything is working fine.